# Difference between android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager and android.app.FragmentManager;

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragmentmanager

I have faced problem while creating fragments. In my mainActivity i am calling this fragment..

```
Fragment fr = new Article();

FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();

fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fr);

fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

but it is not displaying because instead of given two imports I have to add the supprot.v4 one and

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;//correct one
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;// wrong one..
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

and in the fragment class i have to import this

```
import android.app.Fragment;
//instead of the given below..
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Know the problem is solved.. But i am curious about the difference between them. And what is the better way of using fragment. I have created a

`MainActivity which extends Activity`
and in that class i am displaying fragments.

One of my colleague told me to extends mainActivity from `Fragment` . Otherwise i will have to face a lot of problem. Tell me which is the proper way to use . Or what are the benefits or disadvantage of extending mainActivity from `Activity` while using `Fragments`...

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1):

Nepster, that is a good question.

The main difference between the two is that the `android.app.Fragment` provides no support for devices prior to its creation.  So it will work great to just implement `FragmentActivity`.

However, if you want to support phones back to Android 2 you will need to use the `android.support.app.Fragment`.  It's easy to do if you need to so if you don't know what devices you need to support it's good to cover your bases by providing the support.

The difference between FragmentActivity and Activity is that FragmentActivity allows you to use getSupportLoaderManager() and getSupportFragmentManager() while Activity uses getLoaderManager() and getFragmentManager().  Whether it is an advantage or disadvantage depends on whether or not you need the support library associated with FragmentActivity.  That's the only difference, FragmentActivity allows you to use the support library.

Comment: and answer to the rest of my Questoin?

Comment: I have updated my answer to respond to what seems to be the "rest" but I'm not entirely sure what exactly was missing.